# Как показать float данные в python красиво

Tags: python, float

у меня есть значение float `float(balance) = 0.00001` когда я вывожу  это значение в программе, оно выводится как **1e-05**. Как сделать чтобы выводилось так же 0.00001?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33219633/7485582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
balance = 0.00001
print("balance =  {0:7.5f}".format(balance))

balance =  0.00001
```

Comment: Обьясни как работает формат в данном случае, а точнее что делает `0:7`

Comment: @DeNRouN. `0` - порядковый индекс переменной в методе формат, `7` - количество символов которое будет занимать число.  `.5` - сколько символов после запятой выводить.  Для примера `print("balance = |{0:-^27.5f}|".format(balance))` -> `balance = |----------0.00001----------| `  . [Здесь подробней] (https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html)